# jQuery change value after animation is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-animate

This code down never call alert *'ane is true'*.

It is possible to change local variable *'ane'* from jQuery method **"animate"**?

In my code variable *'ane'* is always false. I try this method for change of *'ane'* value:

```
function anim() {
  var ane = false;
  $('#element').animate({left:'100px'}, 5000, function(){ ane = true; });
  while(!ane){}
  alert('ane is true');
}
```

This also does not work for me:

```
function anim() {
  var ane = false;
  var ant = function(){ ane = true; }
  $('#element').animate({left:'100px'}, 5000, ant);
  while(!ane){}
  alert('ane is true');
}
```

Thanks for reply.

Comment: This probably does not work because `while(!ane){}` is blocking everything. Put an `alert` in the callback and see whether it is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/khYNH/)***

```
function anim() {
  var ane = false;
    $('#element').animate({left:'100px'}, 5000, function(){
        ane = true;
        if(!$(this).is('animated')){
            alert(ane);
        }
    });
}
```

Once the animation completes you will be alerted.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has only a single thread. If you use

```
while(!ane){}
```

jQuery can't run, thus not execute the animation, thus not complete the animation and set `ane` to true.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Loktar is correct, but you could omit the condition

```
function anim() {
  var ane = false;
    $('#element').animate({left:'100px'}, 5000, function(){
        ane = true;
        // the animation is already finished
        // if(!$(this).is('animated')){
        //    alert(ane);
        //}
        alert(ane);

    });
}
```

because the function is called when the animation is actually finished.

Using the latest version of jQuery (>= 1.8) you can check if the animation is actually completed using the option **done**:

```
function anim() {
    var ane = false;
    $('#element').animate({width:'100px'}, 
                      {duration: 5000,
                       done: function () {alert("done")}
                      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function anim() {
  var ane = false;
  var ant = function(){ ane = true; }
  $('#element').animate({left:'100px'}, 5000, ant);
  setInterval(function(){ if(ane) { alert('ane is true'); } }, 100); 
}
```

`ane` should eventually be true, because this time the execution is not locked by the while loop.

Comment: I recommend using setTimeout and maybe a call to a function that checks and resets the timeout, just because then you wont keep getting alerts even after the val is true.

Comment: Or you could use clearTimeout within the interval function. I didn't bother adding that as it was kind of getting beyond the scope of the original question...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I used this to continue in the same executed function after animation:

```
// animation part
var ane = false; // check if animation end
$('#element').animate({left:'100px'}, 5000, function(){ane = true;});

// continue only if animation done
var fcb = setInterval(function(){ if(ane) {
  // continue executing function
  clearInterval(fcb); 
  // ...
  // nextCodePart();
  // ...
} }, 20);
```