# Prevent a scroll function to trigger on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, navigation

I have an autohiding header, which hides on scroll down and shows up again on scroll up. I also have two navigation arrows, which allows you to go up and down between sections. The problem though, is when clicking the up-arrow, the menu shows because the site scrolls up. 
So what I'm trying to figure out, but not really can, is how to prevent the autohiding functions to be called when clicking the up-arrow.

This is what triggers the hiding function, which I don't want to be triggered if we are scrolling up when we clicked the up-arrow:

```
//set scrolling variables
var scrolling = false,
    previousTop = 0,
    currentTop = 0,
    scrollDelta = 10,
    scrollOffset = 150;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if( !scrolling ) {
        scrolling = true;
        (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
            ? setTimeout(autoHideHeader, 250)
            : requestAnimationFrame(autoHideHeader);

    }
});
```

And this is the arrow-code:

```
var sections = $('.panel-section');
console.log(sections);
var i =0;
var scrolto = 0;

function next(){

    if(i == 0){
        $('.prev-section').show();
    }
    if(i < sections.length -1){
        i++;
        if(i == sections.length -1){
            $('.next-section').hide();
        }
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 2000);
    }else{
        alert('end reached');
    }
}
function prev(){
    if(i == sections.length -1){
        $('.next-section').show();
    }
    if(i > 0){
        i--;
        if(i == 0){
            $('.prev-section').hide();
        }
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 2000);
    }
}
$('html').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == '38'){
        prev();
    }
    if(e.which == '40'){
        next();
    }
});
$('.next-section').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    next();
});

$('.prev-section').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    prev();
});
```

I think this is the only relevant code, but I might be wrong and if so, I can provide with more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable while you're scrolling due to the button click and don't show the header if that variable is true

```
var prevSectionClick = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if( !scrolling && !prevSectionClick) {
        scrolling = true;
        (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
            ? setTimeout(autoHideHeader, 250)
            : requestAnimationFrame(autoHideHeader);

    }
});
$('.prev-section').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    prevSectionClick=true;
    prev();
    prevSectionClick=false;
});
```

As long as your prev() function stays synchronous this will work. Otherwise, you'll have to deal with the 2 second animation you're introducing inside the function

............

From comments:

```
$('.prev-section').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    prevSectionClick=true;
    prev();
});

function prev(){
    if(i == sections.length -1){
        $('.next-section').show();
    }
    if(i > 0){
        i--;
        if(i == 0){
            $('.prev-section').hide();
        }
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 2000, function() {
            prevSectionClick=false;
        });
    }
    else prevSectionClick=false;
}
```

Comment: The menu still shows. In IDE it says that _the value assigned is never used_ when it comes to this: `prevSectionClick=true;` If I remove `prevSectionClick=false;` from the `$('.prev-section').click` function, it gets the value true, but then it never goes back to false when you start scrolling again.

Comment: I think it has to do with the way jquery's animate works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302017/jquery-change-value-after-animation-is-done

Try what I added?